# How do I turn a python datetime into a string, with readable format date?

Tags: python, datetime, string-formatting

```
t = e['updated_parsed']
dt = datetime.datetime(t[0],t[1],t[2],t[3],t[4],t[5],t[6]
print dt
>>>2010-01-28 08:39:49.000003
```

How do I turn that into a string?:

```
"January 28, 2010"
```

Comment: `dt = datetime.datetime(*t[:7])`

Answer (score 305, accepted):

The datetime class has a method strftime. The Python docs documents the different formats it accepts: [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

For this specific example, it would look something like:

```
my_datetime.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

Answer (score 127):

Here is how you can accomplish the same using python's general formatting function...

```
>>>from datetime import datetime
>>>"{:%B %d, %Y}".format(datetime.now())
```

The formatting characters used here are the same as those used by [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). Don't miss the leading `:`  in the format specifier.

Using format() instead of strftime() in most cases can make the code more readable, easier to write and consistent with the way formatted output is generated...

```
>>>"{} today's date is: {:%B %d, %Y}".format("Andre", datetime.now())
```

Compare the above with the following strftime() alternative...

```
>>>"{} today's date is {}".format("Andre", datetime.now().strftime("%B %d, %Y"))
```

Moreover, the following is not going to work...

```
>>>datetime.now().strftime("%s %B %d, %Y" % "Andre")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    datetime.now().strftime("%s %B %d, %Y" % "Andre")
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

And so on...

Comment: I've been wondering what are the benefits to using format() for this case, over strftime(). Does either method present a benefit other than personal preference? What are the performance differences?

Comment: @Andre Thanks for your question! Personal preferences are often guided by experience. Please see my updated answer for why I prefer format() over strftime(). Performance and Python are two words which do not go well together. I wouldn't be overly concerned with performance if I have decided to use Python. When I need performance I use some statically typed high performance language.

Comment: The format method is simpler in most cases. Compare: `print 'Today is {:%B %d, %Y}'.format(datetime.now())` to `print 'Today is {}'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%B %d, %Y')`. When you are using the format() method anyways, why not use it for the date formatting too?

Answer (score 88):

## Using f-strings, in Python 3.6+.

```py
from datetime import datetime

date_string = f'{datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z}'
date_string
# returns '2024-01-15 23:58:18'
```

```py
LogTimeFormat = f'{datetime.utcnow():%Y%m%d_%H%M%S}'
LogTimeFormat
# returns time in UTC '20240116_055907'
```

Comment: Thank you!  and let's not forget our admins. `LogTimeFormat = f'{datetime.utcnow():%Y%m%d_%H%M%S}'`

Answer (score 35):

very old question, i know. but with the new [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (starting from python 3.6) there are fresh options. so here for completeness:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.now()

# str.format
strg = '{:%B %d, %Y}'.format(dt)
print(strg)  # July 22, 2017

# datetime.strftime
strg = dt.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
print(strg)  # July 22, 2017

# f-strings in python >= 3.6
strg = f'{dt:%B %d, %Y}'
print(strg)  # July 22, 2017
```

[`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) explains what the format specifiers mean.

Answer (score 19):

Python datetime object has a method attribute, which prints in readable format.

```
>>> a = datetime.now()
>>> a.ctime()
'Mon May 21 18:35:18 2018'
>>>
```

Comment: This is one of the best, easiest and quickest ways to get the DateTime in a readable format.

Answer (score 10):

Read [strfrtime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) from the official docs.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are impatient to read the nice official docs [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) :)

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M %B %d, %Y")
'12:11 August 08, 2022'
```

Answer (score -4):

This is for format the date?

```
def format_date(day, month, year):
        # {} betekent 'plaats hier stringvoorstelling van volgend argument'
        return "{}/{}/{}".format(day, month, year)
```