# DateField to String formatting in QuerySEt

Tags: python, django, typeerror, python-docx

```
activitylist = sr.activity_set.all()
cell.paragraphs[0].text = activitylist.values_list('activityPlannedStartDate', flat = True)
```

I am getting an error of: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not datetime.date

`cell.paragraphs[0].text` is a cell in a predefined table in a docx that I build in Word.

Please help with this `TypeError`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2158454/1486443

Comment: Is that only for a datetime.datetime field?

Comment: I am using a DateField: activityPlannedEndDate = models.DateField("Planned End Date")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) method to format date to string.  And use `string.join` to represent values list as a comma-separated string:

```
formatted_dates = [date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for date in
                         activitylist.values_list('activityPlannedStartDate',
                                                  flat=True)]
cell.paragraphs[0].text = ', '.join(formatted_dates)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value, CharField

qs.annotate(
  formatted_date=Func(
    F('date'),
    Value('dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm'),
    function='to_char',
    output_field=CharField()
  )
)
```

This works only with a database that supports the `to_char` [date type formatting function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-formatting.html). `Postgres` provides this function by default. If you use a `MSSQL` backend you could swap `to_char` with `FORMAT`. For `Oracle` consult their documentation, etc.

After the queryset is evaluated this will add the annotation `formatted_date` to each object in the queryset that is returned.

```
[obj.formatted_date for obj in qs]
```