# How to get current time in python and break up into year, month, day, hour, minute?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, time

I would like to get the current time in Python and assign them into variables like `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour`, `minute`. How can this be done in Python 2.7?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2158454/3994485

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current time in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-current-time-in-python)

Answer (score 798, accepted):

The [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) module is your friend:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
# 2015 5 6 8 53 40
```

You don't need separate variables, the attributes on the returned `datetime` object have all you need.

Comment: just a suplyment: `import time   \n   now=time.localtime()       \n   print now.tm_year, now.tm_mon, now.tm_mday, now.tm_hour, now.tm_hour, now.tm_min, now.tm_sec, now.tm_wday, now.tm_yday, now.tm_isdst`

Answer (score 57):

Here's a one-liner that comes in just under the 80 char line max.

```
import time
yr, month, day, hr, minute = map(int, time.strftime("%Y %m %d %H %M").split())
```

Comment: You might want to use `mn` or `minute` instead of `min`, just in case you later need use of the built in `min()` function.

Answer (score 41):

The `datetime` answer by [tzaman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071999/3596187) is much cleaner, but you can do it with the original python `time` module:

```
import time
strings = time.strftime("%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S")
t = strings.split(',')
numbers = [ int(x) for x in t ]
print numbers
```

Output:

```
[2016, 3, 11, 8, 29, 47]
```

Answer (score 15):

By unpacking `timetuple` of datetime object, you should get what you want:

```
from datetime import datetime

n = datetime.now()
t = n.timetuple()
y, m, d, h, min, sec, wd, yd, i = t
```

Comment: Heads up: you are shadowing the builtin function "min"

Answer (score 13):

Let's see how to get and print day,month,year in python from current time:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
year = '{:02d}'.format(now.year)
month = '{:02d}'.format(now.month)
day = '{:02d}'.format(now.day)
hour = '{:02d}'.format(now.hour)
minute = '{:02d}'.format(now.minute)
day_month_year = '{}-{}-{}'.format(year, month, day)

print('day_month_year: ' + day_month_year)
```

result:

```
day_month_year: 2019-03-26
```

Answer (score 10):

**For python 3**

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import time
year = time.strftime("%Y") # or "%y"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use gmtime

```
from time import gmtime

detailed_time = gmtime() 
#returns a struct_time object for current time

year = detailed_time.tm_year
month = detailed_time.tm_mon
day = detailed_time.tm_mday
hour = detailed_time.tm_hour
minute = detailed_time.tm_min
```

Note: A time stamp can be passed to gmtime, default is current time as 
returned by time()

```
eg.
gmtime(1521174681)
```

See [struct_time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time)

Answer (score 2):

Three libraries for accessing and manipulating dates and times, namely datetime, arrow and pendulum, all make these items available in namedtuples whose elements are accessible either by name or index. Moreover, the items are accessible in precisely the same way. (I suppose if I were more intelligent I wouldn't be surprised.)

```
>>> YEARS, MONTHS, DAYS, HOURS, MINUTES = range(5)
>>> import datetime
>>> import arrow
>>> import pendulum
>>> [datetime.datetime.now().timetuple()[i] for i in [YEARS, MONTHS, DAYS, HOURS, MINUTES]]
[2017, 6, 16, 19, 15]
>>> [arrow.now().timetuple()[i] for i in [YEARS, MONTHS, DAYS, HOURS, MINUTES]]
[2017, 6, 16, 19, 15]
>>> [pendulum.now().timetuple()[i] for i in [YEARS, MONTHS, DAYS, HOURS, MINUTES]]
[2017, 6, 16, 19, 16]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an older question, but I came up with a solution I thought others might like.

```
def get_current_datetime_as_dict():
n = datetime.now()
t = n.timetuple()
field_names = ["year",
               "month",
               "day",
               "hour",
               "min",
               "sec",
               "weekday",
               "md",
               "yd"]
return dict(zip(field_names, t))
```

timetuple() can be zipped with another array, which creates labeled tuples. Cast that to a dictionary and the resultant product can be consumed with `get_current_datetime_as_dict()['year']`.

This has a little more overhead than some of the other solutions on here, but I've found it's so nice to be able to access named values for clartiy's sake in the code.