# What is an efficient way to trim a date in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I am trying to trim the current date into day, month and year with the following code.

```
#Code from my local machine
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

five_days_ago = datetime.now()-timedelta(days=5)
# result: 2017-07-14 19:52:15.847476

get_date = str(five_days_ago).rpartition(' ')[0]
#result: 2017-07-14

#Extract the day
day = get_date.rpartition('-')[2]
# result: 14

#Extract the year
year = get_date.rpartition('-')[0])
# result: 2017-07
```

I am not a Python professional because I grasp this language for a couple of months ago but I want to understand a few things here:

1. Why did I receive this 2017-07 if str.rpartition() is supposed to separate a string once you have declared some sort separator (-, /, " ")? I was expecting to receive 2017...
2. Is there an efficient way to separate day, month and year? I do not want to repeat the same mistakes with my insecure code.

I tried my code in the following tech. setups:
local machine with Python 3.5.2 (x64), Python 3.6.1 (x64) and repl.it with Python 3.6.1

[Try the code online, copy and paste the line codes](https://repl.it/languages/python3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current time in python and break up into year, month, day, hour, minute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071886/how-to-get-current-time-in-python-and-break-up-into-year-month-day-hour-minu)

Comment: Possible but that does not explain question 1.

Comment: Read rpartition https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rpartition.html & partition https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/partition.html  You want partition for the year. Not rpartition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

five_days_ago = date.today() - timedelta(days=5)
day = five_days_ago.day
year = five_days_ago.year
```

If what you want is a date (not a date and time), use `date` instead of `datetime`. Then, the day and year are simply properties on the `date` object.

As to your question regarding `rpartition`, it works by splitting on the *rightmost* separator (in your case, the hyphen between the month and the day) - that's what the `r` in `rpartition` means. So `get_date.rpartition('-')` returns `['2017-07', '-', '14']`.

If you want to persist with your approach, your `year` code would be made to work if you replace `rpartition` with `partition`, e.g.:

```
year = get_date.partition('-')[0]
# result: 2017
```

However, there's also a related (better) approach - use `split`:

```
parts = get_date.split('-')
year = parts[0]
month = parts[1]
day = parts[2]
```

Comment: And definitely, I learnt something very valuable today because I thought that .rpartition was the primary tool for splitting strings but I was in such a great mistake.