# Python Only If Time is 5 past the hour

Tags: python, date

I only want to run a piece of code if the time is between specific minutes in an hour but I can't figure out how to get the hour number in Python.

The equivalent code in PHP is:

```
if (intval(date('i', time())) > 15 && intval(date('i', time())) < 32) {
    // any time from hour:16 to hour:33, inclusive
} else {
    // any time until hour:15 or from hour:32
}
```

In Python it would be something like this:

```
import time
from datetime import date
if date.fromtimestamp(time.time()):
   run_my_code()
else:
   print('Not running my code')
```

I'd typically use cron but this is running inside a Lambda and I want to make absolutely sure this code does NOT get run all the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current time in python and break up into year, month, day, hour, minute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071886/how-to-get-current-time-in-python-and-break-up-into-year-month-day-hour-minu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one wasy of doing it.

```
import datetime

# Get date time and convert to a string
time_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%S")    
mins = int(time_now)

# run the if statement
if mins > 10 and mins < 50:
    print(mins, 'In Range')
else:
    print(mins, 'Out of Range')
```

Comment: This is quite an inefficient method of getting the 'minutes' field - 1) format time as a string - HH-MM-SS, 2) retrieve a substring containing only the minutes - why specify the others if you don't want them? 3) parse the string and convert to integer.

Answer (score 1):

The [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) class has attributes that you can use. You are interested in the [`minute` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.minute).

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

minute = datetime.now().minute

if minute > 15 and minute < 32:
    run_my_code()
else:
    print('Not running my code')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner that avoids loading the datetime module:

```
if 5 < int(time.strftime('%M')) < 15:
```

The above code will only run between 5 and 15 minutes past the hour (local time of course).