# Regex to identify years from recent up to 2018

Tags: python, regex

I am using the following code to identify years in my text.

```
import re
match = re.match(r'.*([1-2][0-9]{3})', text)
print(match.group(1))
```

However, this also accepts years such as 2999, 2078 that are still not valid.

Therefore, I would like to know how to identify years till recent in Python (i.e up to 2018).

Comment: Add a condition check: `if int(match.group(1)) <= 2018: ...`

Comment: If you need ourely regexp solution then you can write `r'.*(1[0-9]{3})|(200[0-9])|(201[1-8])' but whats the point in doing that? You can just call `int(text[-4:])` and compare it to 2018

Comment: What does "from recent" mean, since 1900? 2000? 100 years ago? etc. Please edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: List them out one-by-one:

```
r = re.compile(r"(?!\d)(?:1[0-9]{3}|20[01][0-9])(?!\d)")
match = r.search(text)
```

This will give you years 1000 to 2019

---

Option 2: Extract the number, convert to `int` and compare.

```
match = re.match(r'.*([1-2][0-9]{3})', text)
year = int(match.group(0))
if 1000 <= year <= 2019:
    do_your_stuff()
```

---

You can fetch the current year programmatically:

```
from datetime import datetime

year = datetime.now().year
```

Comment: I presume that the year doesn't want to be past the current year? If so I would suggest getting the year from the datetime package instead of hard-coded to 2019 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071886/how-to-get-current-time-in-python-and-break-up-into-year-month-day-hour-minu

Comment: Hi, when I give the text as ""2018 and 2017 in" it returns None. But I want it to return [2018,2017]

Comment: @Emi Use `re.findall`.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to cast the given value to an integer and check if it's bigger than e. g. 1900 and smaler or equal to 2018/2019

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the matched string to the code below, and compare the matched year with the current year, and return `True` if the matched year is equal to or less than the current year.

```
from datetime import datetime

matched_string = "2020"
past = datetime.strptime(matched_string, "%Y")
present = datetime.now()

print(past.date() < present.date())
```

Answer (score 0):

pure regular expression

```
(\d{1,3})|(1\d{3})|(201[0-8])|(200\d)
```