# Is there a way for me to print dates with datetime as dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: python, date, datetime, discord.py

I am currently writing a discord bot, and I want to be able to print today's date as dd/mm/yyyy. I tried *.strftime()* and *.strpdate()* but I can't find out a way to incorporate *.now()*.

```
import time, datetime
from datetime import datetime

@commands.command()
async def date(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send(datetime.now().strpdate('%d:%m:%Y'))
```

This is the output:

*discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'strpdate'*

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071886/how-to-get-current-time-in-python-and-break-up-into-year-month-day-hour-minu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now().strftime('%d:%m:%Y')
'06:07:2020'
```