# Python call datetime current hour?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

Killing two birds with one stone, I have two questions

1. How can I accurately call the current date? Current hour?
2. And how can I accurately call a specific hour? Not specific to a day.

```
from datetime import date, datetime

current_time = datetime.utcnow() # Call current time
start_time = datetime.time.hour(17)
end_time = datetime.time.hour(20)
```

Comment: `timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().hour`, you could do this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current time in python and break up into year, month, day, hour, minute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071886/how-to-get-current-time-in-python-and-break-up-into-year-month-day-hour-minu)

Comment: A specific hour is an `int`, not a `datetime` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close to an answer. Here we go.

```
import datetime
```

after importing the datetime module you just need to call:

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

In case you wanna access the data you have the `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour`, `minute`, `second`, `microsecond` methods:

```
current_time.day # Will return 17
```

To specify a given hour you just have to a variable you have the datetime.time class.

> An idealized time, independent of any particular day, assuming that every day has exactly 24*60*60 seconds. (There is no notion of “leap seconds” here.) Attributes: hour, minute, second, microsecond, and tzinfo.

```
start_time = datetime.time(17, 25, 30) # (17:25:30)
```

And the same as before. Accessing data can be done by calling its methods.

```
start_time.hour # will return 17
```

Here you have the documentation: :)
[datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Answer (score 3):

### Using the `datetime` module in Python

Examples given with ***Python 3***

### Get current time

```py
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S") # H - hour, M- minute, S - second
print("Current Time =", current_time)
```

### Get current hour

```py
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

current_hour = now.strftime("%H") 
print("Current hour =", current_hour)
```

### Get current date

```py
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
print("Today's date:", today)
```

Likewise, use `%S` for second, `%M` for minute, and `%H` for hour.
and `%d` for day, `%m` for month, and `%Y` for year.

### Extras

### Print date and time together

```py
from datetime import datetime

# datetime object containing current date and time
now = datetime.now()
 
print("now =", now)

# dd/mm/YY H:M:S
dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print("date and time =", dt_string)
```

### Print according to time-zone

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

tz_NY = pytz.timezone('America/New_York') 
datetime_NY = datetime.now(tz_NY)
print("NY time:", datetime_NY.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

tz_London = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
datetime_London = datetime.now(tz_London)
print("London time:", datetime_London.strftime("%H:%M:%S
```

sources:

[**Date**](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/current-datetime)

[**Time**](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/current-time)

Also check out: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071886/how-to-get-current-time-in-python-and-break-up-into-year-month-day-hour-minu)