# Issues with data return by raw sql query in Django

Tags: python, mysql, json, django, rawsql

I am fetching data from db using raw SQl queries , I am following [these](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) django docs.
As you can see in django docs we have a function **dictfetchall** which returns dict with field names and values. I am converting this dict to json as per my requirements but as you can see in output cursor return values with unicode like

```
> 54360982L
> for date - datetime.date(2015, 8, 3)
> for decimal - Decimal('0.63')
```

Thus dict cannot be convert into json as it will raise error `Decimal('0.63') is not JSON serializable` . So How i can prevent **raw sql** to sent simple values from db or need to edit **dictfetchall** function , if yes then where ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960516/python-json-serialize-a-decimal-object

Comment: @TanveerAlam But its only for Decimal , you know json will create issues for others too like Date

Comment: You can make your datetime also in string format http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158347/how-do-i-turn-a-python-datetime-into-a-string-with-readable-format-date