# Python export datetime to csv

Tags: python, django, csv, datetime, export

I have this code

```
import csv

def export_failures_all(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="failures.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter=';', dialect = 'excel')
    response.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))
    writer.writerow(['Maszyna', 'Wydział', 'Opis', 'Data dodania', 'Data rozpoczęcia naprawy', 'Data zakończenia naprawy', 'Zgłaszający', 'Przyjęte przez', 'Status'])
    awarie = Awaria.objects.all().values_list('maszyna__nazwa', 'wydzial__nazwa', 'description', 'add_date', 'repair_date', 'remove_date', 'user__username', 'sur__username', 'status__nazwa').order_by('-id')

    for awaria in awarie:
        writer.writerow(awaria)

    return response
```

The problem I have it's with `add_date`, `repair_date`, `remove_date`  because there are `DateTimeField` and in csv file they are with seconds:

```
2017-02-14 09:50:19.271833+00:00

2017-02-14 08:38:09.362218+00:00
```

and I want like this:

```
2017-02-14 09:50

2017-02-14 08:38
```

Any ideas how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format it before by doing:

`my_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")`

From [How do I turn a python datetime into a string, with readable format date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158347/how-do-i-turn-a-python-datetime-into-a-string-with-readable-format-date)

To update all the dates in your list (assuming its a list of lists)

```
values_list = [[x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime) else x for x in row] for row in values_list]
```

Comment: You can with list comprehension. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly.

Important:
import datetime NOT from datetime import datetime