# Change datetime object back to string in python

Tags: python

If I have a datetime object such as `datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 20, 15, 0)`, how do I convert it back to a string in the format of `"2017-07-20-15-00"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn a python datetime into a string, with readable format date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158347/how-do-i-turn-a-python-datetime-into-a-string-with-readable-format-date)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158454/6468413

Answer (score 2):

python has date formattting built-in either using [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=format#format) or the new [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) in python >= 3.6:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime(2017, 7, 20, 15, 0)

# str.format
strg = '{:%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S}'.format(dt)
print(strg)  # 2017-07-20 15-00-00

# datetime.strftime
strg = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')
print(strg)  # 2017-07-20 15-00-00

# f-strings in python >= 3.6
strg = f'{dt:%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S}'
print(strg)  # 2017-07-20 15-00-00
```

you can tweak the format string according to your needs. [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) explains what the format specifiers mean.