# How to convert timestamp (datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 1, 0) into 2012-01-01 01:00:00

Tags: python, datetime

Could I please get help with converting my date and time, dataː `01/01/2012 01:00` into something like `2012-01-01 01:00:00`ʔ I have tried doing

```
datetime = [datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0) + datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for 
i in range(9)]

dates=[datetime.strptime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for x in datetime]
```

This returns the errorː

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strptime'
```

My datetime's in my csv file look like thisː

```
01/01/2012 01:00
01/01/2012 02:00
01/01/2012 03:00
01/01/2012 04:00
01/01/2012 05:00
01/01/2012 06:00
01/01/2012 07:00
01/01/2012 08:00
01/01/2012 09:00
```

I believe this must be very straight forward but i can't seem to get my head around this. help with this will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn a python datetime into a string, with readable format date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158347/how-do-i-turn-a-python-datetime-into-a-string-with-readable-format-date)

Comment: Don't name your variable as module name `datetime`.

Comment: @mvp Thank you for replying. I have changed my variables names as so: D = [datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0) + D.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(16800)] dates=[datetime.strptime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for x in D] but I am getting the error ot "AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime" Is there anything else that could need changing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have named your list `datetime` which overrides the `datetime` module. So `datetime.strptime` call fails.

Give a different name to your list.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have changed my variables names as so: D = [datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0) + D.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(16800)]
dates=[datetime.strptime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for x in D]  but I am getting the error ot "AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime"  Is there anything else that needs changing?

Comment: Looks like you have imported the `datetime` submodule from the `datetime` module by doing `from datetime import datetime`. Instead, just import the top level module `datetime` by doing `import datetime`

Comment: When I import the top level module I get the original error of "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strptime'" in the second line with the variable named dates, could there be a different issue?

Comment: If you have renamed your variable, there is no way you can get the origin error. Check again if you have renamed all occurrences