# print a datetime and a rounded float in a tuple without function name, quotations or parenthesis in the most pythonic way

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, format, string-formatting

when one prints the following:

```
import datetime
data = (datetime.datetime.now(), '%.3f' % float(8/9))
print(data)
```

he/she begets:

> (datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 16, 23, 58, 19, 314376), '0.889')

However, often one would like python to write:

> 2018-10-16 23:58:19, 0.889

There are of course many fine ways to wood pack here and there, but which is the way of the python?

PS
This is not a question about ways to print a `datetime` instance as a readable string (there are plenty and easily accessible answers on SO). This question additionally asks to remove the quotation marks around the two strings in `data`, both of which emerge in different ways when printing a tuple. There are also many easily accessible answers on ways to do this. The question is how to combine these things in the most readable/pythonic way.

Comment: See also [How do I turn a python datetime into a string, with readable format date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158347/how-do-i-turn-a-python-datetime-into-a-string-with-readable-format-date)