# Change how datetime object is printed from print()?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

When printing dates in the `datetime` module of Python 3.6, they look like:

```
>> from datetime.date import date
>> print(date(2018,1,30))
2018-01-30
```

Is it possible to change the format of the output of `print()` for `datetime.date` objects?

My desired outcome is:

```
>> print(date(2018,1,30))
30/01/18
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn a python datetime into a string, with readable format date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158347/how-do-i-turn-a-python-datetime-into-a-string-with-readable-format-date)

Comment: Specifically in this case: `print(date(2018,1,30).strftime("%d/%m/%y"))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `datetime` formatting function - `strftime` - taking a formatting string [described in detail here](https://pymotw.com/3/datetime/).

You may also want to review **Advanced date formatting** from the following answer: [How to print a date in a regular format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-a-date-in-a-regular-format)