# how to get only date string from a long string

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, parsing, python-dateutil

I know there are lots of Q&As to extract datetime from string, such as [dateutil.parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276180/extracting-date-from-a-string-in-python), to extract datetime from a string

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
dparser.parse('something sep 28 2017 something',fuzzy=True).date()

output: datetime.date(2017, 9, 28)
```

but my question is how to know which part of string results this extraction, e.g. i want a function that also returns me 'sep 28 2017'

```
datetime, datetime_str = get_date_str('something sep 28 2017 something')
outputs: datetime.date(2017, 9, 28), 'sep 28 2017'
```

any clue or any direction that i can search around?

Comment: You can use `strftime` to convert datetime object to string (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158347/how-do-i-turn-a-python-datetime-into-a-string-with-readable-format-date/22842734)

Comment: I don't think this is particularly simple to do, unfortunately. The string that dateutil found is not guaranteed to be contiguous, so "It happened on Sep 29, 1947 at around 8:45" will return `1947-09-29 08:45`. That said, `fuzzy_with_tokens` is a good place to start. It gives you the inverse of what you want.

Comment: @Paul thanks, I'm also thinking of `fuzzy_with_tokens` which list a number of tokens to exclude, but it includes space `('something ', '  ', 'something')` which made it a bit challenging. I will try digging a way of it and post my solution later in this direction

Comment: @SruthiV thanks, but I'm finding the original string rather than convert datetime to string, datetime package has a simpler solution for such conversion by append`.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend to the discussion with @Paul and following the solution from @alecxe, I have proposed the following solution, which works on a number of testing cases, I've made the problem slight challenger:

**Step 1: get excluded tokens**

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser

ostr = 'something sep 28 2017 something abcd'
_, excl_str = dparser.parse(ostr,fuzzy_with_tokens=True)
```

gives outputs of:

```
excl_str:     ('something ', ' ', 'something abcd')
```

**Step 2 : rank tokens by length**

```
excl_str = list(excl_str)
excl_str.sort(reverse=True,key = len)
```

gives a sorted token list:

```
excl_str:   ['something abcd', 'something ', ' ']
```

**Step 3: delete tokens and ignore space element**

```
for i in excl_str:
    if i != ' ':
        ostr = ostr.replace(i,'') 
return ostr
```

gives a final output

```
ostr:    'sep 28 2017 '
```

***Note:*** step 2 is required, because it will cause problem if any shorter token a subset of longer ones. e.g., in this case, if deletion follows an order of  `('something ', ' ', 'something abcd')`, the replacement process will remove `something` from `something abcd`, and `abcd` will never get deleted, ends up with `'sep 28 2017 abcd'`

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem! There is no direct way to get the parsed out date string out of the bigger string with `dateutil`. The problem is that `dateutil` parser does not even have this string available as an intermediate result as it really builds parts of the future `datetime` object on the fly and character by character ([source](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/master/dateutil/parser/_parser.py#L732-L856)).

It, though, also collects a list of skipped tokens which is probably your best bet. As this list is ordered, you can loop over the tokens and replace the first occurrence of the token:

```
from dateutil import parser


s = 'something sep 28 2017 something'
parsed_datetime, tokens = parser.parse(s, fuzzy_with_tokens=True)

for token in tokens:
    s = s.replace(token.lstrip(), "", 1)

print(s)  # prints "sep 28 2017"
```

I am though not 100% sure if this would work in all the possible cases, especially, with the different whitespace characters (notice how I had to workaround things with `.lstrip()`).