# How to convert datetime.datetime(YYYY,mm,dd,HH,MM,SS) format to decimal YYYYmm.DDHH

Tags: python-3.x

am stuck trying to figure out how to convert extracted "datetime.datetime(YYYY, mm, dd, HH, MM, SS)" format to decimal "YYYYmm.DDHH"

I have tried code below but it's not taking me any further

```
my_date = datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 28, 13, 50, 36)
def check_date_type(d):
        if type(d) is datetime.datetime:
        return d
        if type(d) is list:
        return d[0]

 print(check_date_type(my_date))
```

I expect an output as below.
NOTE that February is presented as '02' in the expected output

```
201602.2813
```

Comment: Tried `datetime.strftime` with a suitable format string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn a python datetime into a string, with readable format date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158347/how-do-i-turn-a-python-datetime-into-a-string-with-readable-format-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why you want this, but here you go.

---

```
import datetime
from time import strftime

my_date = datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 28, 13, 50, 36)

my_date = my_date.strftime("%Y%m.%d%H")

print(my_date)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `strftime` from the `datetime` library to convert the returned datetime into a formatted string...

```
my_date = datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 28, 13, 50, 36)
def check_date_type(d):
    if type(d) is datetime.datetime:
        return d
    if type(d) is list:
        return d[0]

 print(check_date_type(my_date).strftime('%Y%m.%d%H')) #<----Custom format string
```

[This](http://strftime.org/) is a good reference for strftime formatting

Comment: you beat me to it :D

Comment: @Fadi it's all about the quick fingers xD

Answer (score 0):

@jdub 's answer is the neatest, but if you want to write *your* way, convert it to a set of strings and concatenate the strings as you wish:

```
import datetime
my_date = datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 28, 3, 50, 36)

def add_zero(x):
    zerox = str(x) if x>9 else '0'+str(x)
    return zerox

def check_date_type(d):
    if type(d) is datetime.datetime:
        yy = str(d.year)
        mm = add_zero(d.month)
        dd = add_zero(d.day)
        hh = add_zero(d.hour)
        nn = add_zero(d.minute)
        return yy+mm+dd+':'+hh+nn
    if type(d) is list:
        return d[0]

print(check_date_type(my_date))
```

Comment: thank you very much. this works on the whole string