# Python Time without seconds

Tags: python, time

So I need to display current time, I only print now.hour and now.minutes, however there is always 00 that's displayed for seconds that I would like to take away

this is my code

```
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(datetime.time(now.hour, now.minute))
```

this is my out put

```
16:40:00
```

Comment: Simply don't construct a new time object to print. Try `print(f"{now.hour}:{now.minute}")`. Note that this _will not_ add leading zeros or other useful time formatting, but that can be added trivially by referencing the documentation for formatting strings.

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158347/how-do-i-turn-a-python-datetime-into-a-string-with-readable-format-date

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strftime` to format the time stored in now.

```
now
>2020-02-17 09:47:52.429173

print(datetime.strftime(now, '%H:%M'))
09:47
```

The string located in `datetime.strftime(--, 'here')` defines the formatting that will be returned. You can find more of `strftime`'s formatting specifications [here](https://strftime.org/).