# How to convert a datetime to a string as shown?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

*using python 3.9*

I want to create a program that instead of printing `2/28/2021`, it prints `Sunday, 2, Feb, 2021`.

Comment: Have you read the `strftime()` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I turn a python datetime into a string, with readable format date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158347/how-do-i-turn-a-python-datetime-into-a-string-with-readable-format-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to achieve a human-readable string.

```py
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.now()
print(a.strftime("%a, %d, %B, %Y")) # Sun, 28, February, 2021
print(a.strftime("%A, %d, %B, %Y")) # Sunday, 28, February, 2021

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "sv_SE") # swedish locale
print(a.strftime("%a, %d, %B, %Y")) # sön, 28, februari, 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%A, %-d, %b, %Y')
print(x)  # output: Sunday, 28, Feb, 2021

x = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%-m/%d/%Y')
print(x)  # output: 2/28/2021
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with the datetime method `strftime`.

```py
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.now().strftime("%A %d. %B %Y"))
```

Comment: for me it worked when i wrote it like this 
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
    
print(now.strftime("%A %d. %B %Y"))