# convert YY-M-D HH:MI:SS into readable string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have the time like `2021-05-03 14:51:56.769715`. I need to convert into readable string like
`May 3, 2021, 2:51:56 PM` in python.I need to pass the timezone also while converting it.

Is there any way we can do it in python?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: You're looking for `datetime.strftime()`

Comment: And `strptime()` to parse the original string.

Comment: `datetime.fromisoformat("2021-05-03 14:51:56.769715").strftime("%B %d, %Y, %I:%M:%S %p")`? See https://strftime.org/ for more formatting / parsing directives.

Comment: related: [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date), [How do I turn a python datetime into a string, with readable format date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158347/how-do-i-turn-a-python-datetime-into-a-string-with-readable-format-date)

Comment: Is there any way to pass timezone with it?

Answer (score 1):

This should be OK with the format you want:

```
from datetime import datetime

# Original string
str_date = '2021-05-03 14:51:56.769715'

# Datetime object creation from original string
obj_date = datetime.strptime(str_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

# Result string with the desired format
converted_str = datetime.strftime(obj_date, '%b %-d, %Y, %-I:%-M:%-S %p')

# Print the result
print(converted_str)
```

The above code would print `May 3, 2021, 2:51:56 PM`, just as you expect. However, I have guessed that you would prefer not to have zero-padded minutes and seconds, but if you would like to you should then use `%M` and `%S` instead of `%-M` and `%-S`.

For more information about date formatting in Python you should check the [Python strftime reference](https://strftime.org/)

Comment: Thanks for replying it.I tried like strftime("%b %d,%Y,%-I:%M:%-S %p").Is there any way to pass timezone along with it?

Comment: You can use %z (for timezone's numeric offset) or %Z (for timezone abbreviations)