# python date format change

Tags: python, datetime

How can I change the format of a date

```
var_time="2021-05-17T00:00:00Z"
```

to `2021-05-17 00:00:00`?

Comment: You're asking how to replace the capital `T` and drop the `Z`?  This is covered in any tutorial on string processing.  If this is a `datetime` object -- as it should be, if  you need to do this more than once -- then the formatting info is in the package documentation.

Comment: Why do you need to "convert" anything? `string.split('T')` would get you half way to what you want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should work after taking off the trailing "Z" :

```py
from datetime import datetime
new_var_time = datetime.fromisoformat(var_time[:-1]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: thanks Amin, it is working

Comment: @George Welcome ! Consider validating / accepting the answer plz - thanks

Comment: sure, how can we convert this new_var_time into unixepoch time?

Comment: @George `posix_var_time = datetime.fromisoformat(var_time[:-1]).timestamp()`

Comment: could you correct, posix_var_time = datetime.fromisoformat(var_time[:-1]).timestamp() –

Comment: @George I don't understand. Correct what ?

Comment: do not strip the `Z` - it denotes UTC; if you just ignore it, you'll get naive datetime which Python treats as local time, not UTC.

Answer (score 2):

The Data format you have is [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) so you need to convert this to the desired format. Here is what I did:

```
from datetime import datetime

s= "2021-05-17T00:00:00Z"

yourdate = datetime.fromisoformat(s.replace('Z','+00:00'))
yourdate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

The Output will be this:

```
'2021-05-17 00:00:00'
```

I don't know if this is the best way but I hope I could help.

Source:

- [How do I translate an ISO 8601 datetime string into a Python datetime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969285/how-do-i-translate-an-iso-8601-datetime-string-into-a-python-datetime-object)
- [How do I turn a python datetime into a string, with readable format date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158347/how-do-i-turn-a-python-datetime-into-a-string-with-readable-format-date)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether your var_time is a string or a time/datetime obeject?
If this variable is a string, you can use the following:

```
import datetime

string = '2021-05-17T00:00:00Z'
date_dt1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
print(date_dt1)
```

print:

```
2021-05-17 00:00:00
```

Comment: do not use a literal `Z` in the parsing directive (use `%z` instead) - the Z denotes UTC; if you just ignore it, you'll get naive datetime which Python treats as local time, not UTC.

Comment: @MrFuppes, you are right. Thank you for the note.